How to compute intersections of annihilators of subsets $S$ of a module over a polynomial quotient ring $R$?
Suppose I have the polynomial quotient ring $R = \mathbb{F}_2[x,y]/\langle x^m+1,y^n+1\rangle$, with a subset $S$ of a module of that ring. How to compute the intersection of two annihilators $\text{Ann}_R(S)$ of different elements of that subset?
Ex. Let's take $m=n=3$. What polynomial $s[x,y]$ satisfies both $(1+x)s[x,y]=0$ and $(1+y^2)s[x,y]=0$? How to generalise this without explicitly computing solutions by hand? How to quantify the number of solutions, i.e. the cardinality of the intersection of the annihilators?

If you are just considering polynomials dependent of one variable as in your example, then studying decomposition of $x^m+1,y^n+1$ would be helpful. For polynomials dependent of 2 variables or arbitrary modules, I would say the situation is very complicated, but if you understand the annihilator of the 2 elements, you may be able to find some suitable annihilator on some common associated prime ideals.
